# how can I get a larger stack trace from a node.js network error?

Tags: node.js

I get this error:

```
Error: accept EMFILE
at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1017:24)
```

from a node.js app.  Can I get a line number of my code that calls TCP.onconnection in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, because your code isn't calling `TCP.onconnection`.  That's an event handler, so an event is triggering it.  This is one of the reasons event-based programming is difficult to debug.

I think you'll have some luck looking into what that error means, though.  Some searching reveals that you're hitting a file descriptor limit, which can probably be increased (but that would be OS-dependent, so I can't tell you how without more info).

Answer (score 1):

EMFILE occurs when there is too many files are opened in the system. To increase this limit, look at [Linux Increase The Maximum Number Of Open Files / File Descriptors (FD)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) or revise your code that you close the opened connections when their job is finished. Or If you need too many files open, just increase this value to a reasonable size.